# Why does accruacy of the CNN drop when I remove a filter and its associated weights?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensor

The `model` architecture is `Conv2D with 32 filters` -> `Flatten` -> `Dense` -> `Compile` -> `Fit`

[image]

I deleted the last filter from the first layer and the corresponding Fully connected layer in this model using

```
w,b = model.layers[0].get_weights()
w = np.delete(w, [32], -1)
b = np.delete(b, [32], 0)

w_2,b_2 = model.layers[2].get_weights()
w_2 = w_2[:20956,:]
```

I use 20956 because the output of the first layer is 26 x 26 x 31, which is an image dimension in 2D multiply by a number of channels.

I create a new model called `model_1` using:

```
# Input stays the same
model_1 = Sequential()

# New modified conv layer
model_1.add(Conv2D(31, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape,
                 kernel_initializer='he_normal'))

model_1.add(Flatten())
model_1.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))


model_1.layers[0].set_weights([w,b])
model_1.layers[2].set_weights([w_2,b_2])

model_1.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer="Adam",
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I can confirm that the weights are the same by doing `model_1.layers[0].get_weights()[0] == model.layers[0].get_weights()[0][:,:,:,:31]` and `model_1.layers[2].get_weights()[0] == model.layers[2].get_weights()[0][:20956,:]`which returns True.

[image]

When I do

```
score = model_1.evaluate(x_test_reshape, y_test)

print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

score = model.evaluate(x_test_reshape, y_test)

print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

The accuracy drops from 98% to 10%, any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are essentially doing is removing a channel from the last convolutional layer. Intuitively it may sound like this is not a big deal and the remaining 31 channel will still make the network perform well. In reality all convolution channels interact with each other in the dense layer that follows, but since this interaction is missing one of the channels of information it was optimized on it's accuracy will drop.

Another way to think of this is to view your network as a function of sequential steps that takes as input an image and as output a label with 98% accuracy. Removing a fraction (1/32) of calculations in this function will change the outcomes, and likely give worse results since the function is optimized with these calculations still present. You are removing a part of the function that is apparently crucial to reach the high accuracy.

You can test this by training your new model with 31 channels for a short time. Since the new model only needs to re-learn the function of the deleted channel, it should quickly reach the high performance again.